# c++ alert timer with little cpu load

Tags: c++, windows, performance, timer

I want to write a small alert timer on windows using c++ and msvc2010. The timer needs to trigger a status message after a couple of minutes. I know how to check the system time using c++ and I know there is sleep function in windows api. How can I implement a timer with very little cpu load? For example, I don't want to check the system time every couple of milliseconds to trigger the status message when the trigger time is reached. Do I create cpu load, when using things like sleep(600000) in an extra thread or are there more efficient ways to wait a couple of minutes and execute some code afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed busy-wait and poll the time. Even a `Sleep(1)` will be enough that your program will be barely measurable.

I used to do it "back in the day" and even on my PII 233 Mhz running multiple threads doing this it barely made a dent in the CPU usage.

Comment: thanks for the quick response to mathematician1975 and Joachim Pileborg. So its not the worst idea to create a thread and use sleep(600000) to wait 10 minutes? I can accept an inaccuracy of 100 ms.

Comment: @user1993851 Quite the opposite, your program will do nothing for around ten minutes, and by nothing I really mean nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a thread, write a continuous loop inside which you just sleep for the time interval that your trigger needs to run at then print your message. If you need to run it at 2 minutes, why choose multiple small sleep values and check the time? That would be a waste of CPU time.